# Identifying the source of an SMTP process

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu, smtp

Wonder if someone would be able to give me a bit of advice on identifying the source of a potentially dodgy process running on a Linux VPS I have provisioned.

Had a security breach earlier this week with some nasty files being dropped into the /tmp directory. Been keeping an eye on the processes running on the server, and while I was able to find the source of some of them using the process ID and the command

```
ls -l /proc/<PID>/cwd
```

there are also loads of SMTP processes running all the time which just don't feel like they should be running.  This is the kind of thing I'm talking about

```
postfix  22808  0.0  0.1  44320  4344 ?        S    16:45   0:00 smtp -t unix -u -c
postfix  22815  0.0  0.1  44320  4356 ?        S    16:45   0:00 smtp -t unix -u -c
postfix  22819  0.0  0.1  44320  4280 ?        S    16:45   0:00 smtp -t unix -u -c
postfix  22823  0.0  0.1  44320  4384 ?        S    16:45   0:00 smtp -t unix -u -c
postfix  22827  0.0  0.1  44320  4276 ?        S    16:45   0:00 smtp -t unix -u -c
postfix  22831  0.0  0.1  44320  4416 ?        S    16:45   0:00 smtp -t unix -u -c
```

How can I tell what these are, where they are being fired etc.

Thanks

Comment: stop postfix in the mean time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also discovered the same commands being run on my (Ubuntu 14.04) laptop, though far fewer and less frequent.

I discovered this was postfix periodically retrying delivering mail that had failed to send when I was experimenting with the `sendmail` command months ago.

I was able to view the mail queue using the command `postqueue -p` (manpage [here](http://www.postfix.org/postqueue.1.html)) to find out the destination email addresses of the messages. Then, I deleted all messages in the queue using `sudo postsuper -d ALL`.